# Google App Script Error when Testing as add-on

Tags: google-apps-script

When attempting to Run->Test as add-on... for a simple Google Apps script, selecting the "Select Doc" button for the Test as add-on dialog, the following error is issued.

> Unable to load file Try to load it again or send an error report.

It doesn't matter what Auth method I select or what browser (cleared cash, incognito)I use, the error persists.

Comment: Would it be possible for you to perhaps share the code snippet with us? Please remove any personal/confidential data that you may have on it.

Comment: Welcome. Did you notice this this exact same question was asked recently: https://stackoverflow.com/q/58565130/1330560. There's a link to similar 2018 question where the OP did have some success. Have you tried that?

Comment: Does your add-on include a custom function?

Comment: There is already an [Issue reported](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/143264060) about this. Please follow that for help.

Comment: @SourabhChoraria - I honestly don't believe this issue is code dependent, since I've tried this from many new scripts (all simple and from others that used to work). However, per your request and willingness to help, I am posting a link to a code snippet I have tried.

https://github.com/gsuitedevs/apps-script-samples/blob/master/picker/code.gs

To reiterate, I have tried a snip of super simple code for adding a simple add-on menu which used to work. I was able to select a Doc to test it on but this no longer works.

Comment: @Tedinoz - I did see the post you shared. None of the suggestions worked. New browser, clear cache, restart machine(hehe).

Comment: @ZektorH - Thank you for sharing the link to the Issue Tracker. I will follow there. Thank you all for your guidance and suggestions.